# Converting Depth first search to bread first search in python for decision tree networking

Tags: python, decision-tree, depth-first-search

I've been assigned to implement the decision tree algorithm. So far, I've managed to find all the nodes/leafs but I have them in a flat 1d array. How can I label them such that I can extract visual representation? 
I have the list of the nodes following left-most dept first search, referring the picture: [comedy,guns,leaf,lawyers, leaf,leaf,guns,leaf,leaf]

What I need is labels like comedy: 1 guns:1.1 leaf 1.1.1 lawyers: 1.1.2 etc

My code basically works like the one in this scheme:

```
    track=0
    def create node(dataset):
       select best attribute
       save attribute with track #
       track+=1

       if this attribute has sub-options:
          track*=10 #to indicate new depth level
          create appropriate decision set
          create_node(newdataset)
       else:
          pass #interestingly this bottom part called multiple times
```

track metohd did not help me, I thought it can keep track of inside loops etc but it failed. Any suggestion is much appreciated

[image]

Comment: The right way to implement depth-first search is by putting all the children of your nodes into a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) when you see them and then getting the next node from the stack, repeating until stack is empty. Breadth-first search is exactly the same, but uses a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) instead.

Comment: can you be more specific? I already have succesully found all the nodes, but I cannot differentiate ordering ie which is connectod to which, but it consistently tracks left-and depth first result. Should I change searching algorithm whole together? I thought there would be a simple trick that label each node to know whom it is connected

Comment: I think it is best to provide some [pseudocode](http://www.egr.unlv.edu/~larmore/Courses/CSC477/bfsDfs.pdf) at this point. The point is that stacks and queues take care of the order of your traversal for you - this is why introductory algorithm courses use these structures in their DFS and BFS implementations. Beyond that, I cannot help you - a reference to an orthodox implementation is the most I can give.